# Send email to multiple recipients in one call using AWS SES (PHP SDK)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

Is there a way to send an email message to multiple recipients just making **one** call to AWS? I want the recipient to only see their email address as the only address in the *to* field.

There is no mention of anything like that in the documentation. The other alternative I've think of is using an almighty loop.The problem with this is that if I have 100 recpients I need to make 100 calls to the API.

Comment: This is one of the limitations of SES. You would have to make an API call for each recipient.

Comment: It's a shame, because other major players (Mailgun and Mandrill) have that option.

Comment: Mailgun, Mandrill etc. are higher-level services. You would build a service like Mailgun on top of something like SES. SES is a very low-level service. I recommend using a service like Mailgun or Mandrill instead of SES.

Comment: any solution..?

Answer (score 2):

I solved with the SendBulkTemplatedEmail API operation.

For more information take a look here: https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/introducing-email-templates-and-bulk-sending/